# CI CD Pipeline - Non Source Control Triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, triggers, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am trying to figure out how to trigger a CI CD pipeline from a non source control trigger.
My plan is to use a Google Web Form, to collect all of the variables needed in my scripts, keeping the on boarding process easy enough for non technical staff. Using the Google Forms API Script Editor, I take the submit response JSON, and do a Put to an s3 Bucket / Object.

I would like that PUT (Write Operation), to trigger a CI CD Pipeline.

The CI CD tool is not important, as it seems all CI CD Tools can only use **outgoing** Web Hooks to push to something, like a Slack Channel, and not **ingest**, like an API, or POST / PUT / Event.

**My Question:**
Is it possible to trigger a Pipeline using a PUT or POST?
Tools i would ideally like to use, would be Gitlab CI, Or even Jenkins if it opens up more possibilities.

I have done alot of reading, and am having a hard time coming up with a solution. I would think this was something people would use often, rather than just a simply commit or merge to a source Control Branch...

From what i have Gathered, the API Endpoints of CI Tools, can only process a source control trigger.

Please if anyone have any input on how to achieve this. I am willing to figure out how to create an API, if that somehow helps.

I would like to focus on AWS atm, but the goals would be to also use this solution, or its equivalent in Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those new to pipelines like me, and looking for similar guidance with Gitlab CI:
The same kind of curl request can be made to trigger a pipeline.

However for my specific question, i was looking to trigger the pipeline by sending a POST to the Gitlab CI API directly using HTTPS endpoint. Curl command did not fit my needs

**To achieve this, you can use the Gitlab CI Webhook, for other projects:**
Just fill in the Ref (branch name), and the Gitlab Project ID

**Example:**

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/19577683/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token=4785b192773907c280845066093s93
```

**To use the curl command, to hit the Gitlab Projects Trigger API, similar to Jenkins:**
Simply supply the Tigger Token, you create in the Project / CI CD / Trigger section of Gitlab, and specify the Ref, which is a branch name, or tag

**Example:**

```
curl -X POST \
     -F token=4785b192773907c280845066093s93 \
     -F ref=master \
     https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/19577683/trigger/pipeline
```

Answer (score 1):

In the job settings, scroll to Build Triggers section and find a checkbox named "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)". You need to provide a token (so only people who know the token may trigger your job). Once this is done, you can trigger a pipeline using `curl`:

```
curl 'myjenkins.mycompany.net/job/MyJobName/build?token=myverysecrettoken&cause=Cause+I+Decided+So'

curl 'myjenkins.mycompany.net/job/MyJobName/buildWithParameters?PARAM1=string1&PARAM2=string2&token=myverysecrettoken'
```

See also [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/tree/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd) for examples.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I know nothing of Jenkins, but I will try to figure out how to use your provider answer. Do you happen to know if gitlab pipeline can some how do a remote trigger?